# Issue with Collabora CODE, Nextcloud & Nginx using docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nextcloud

I am trying to get a `docker-compose.yaml` together to run Nextcloud and Collabora CODE via Nginx Proxy Manager.

So far I have Nginx and Nextcloud working really nicely with persistent volumes so that my configs survive `kill` & `rm`. My issue is that I cannot get my Collabora CODE instance to link to Nextcloud. There are multiple bits that I might have got wrong so I'll dump as much info as I can here.

[image]

I have the following subdomains all pointing at my server:

`collabora.domain.tld` `nextcloud.domain.tld` `nginx.domain.tld`

... and set up as proxy hosts:
[image]

As I mentioned, the Nginx and Nextcloud setups are great. When I point my browser at `collabora.domain.tld` I see the `OK` message. I can also access the admin page at `collabora.domain.tld/loleaflet/dist/admin/admin.html`

The NPM entry for `collabora.domain.tld` is below:
[image]
[image]

My docker-compose.yaml has gone through several iterations in an attempt to get this working, but my current attempt is below:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  nextcloud-data:
  nextcloud-db:
  npm-data:
  npm-ssl:
  npm-db:

networks:
  frontend:
  backend:

services:
  code:
    image: collabora/code:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - password=${COLLABORA_PASSWORD:?Not defined!}
      - username=${COLLABORA_USERNAME:?Not defined!}
      - domain=${COLLABORA_DOMAIN:?Not defined!}
    expose:
      - "9980"
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend

  nextcloud-app:
    image: nextcloud:stable
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - nextcloud-data:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${NC_MYSQL_PASSWORD:?Not defined!}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud-user
      - MYSQL_HOST=nextcloud-db
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend

  nextcloud-db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW --innodb-file-per-table=1 --skip-innodb-read-only-compressed
    volumes:
      - nextcloud-db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${NC_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:?Not defined!}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${NC_MYSQL_PASSWORD:?Not defined!}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud-user
    networks:
      - backend

npm-app:
    image: jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "81:81"
      - "443:443"
    environment:
      - DB_MYSQL_HOST=npm-db
      - DB_MYSQL_PORT=3306
      - DB_MYSQL_USER=npm-user
      - DB_MYSQL_PASSWORD=${NPM_MYSQL_PASSWORD:?Not defined!}
      - DB_MYSQL_NAME=npm
    volumes:
      - npm-data:/data
      - npm-ssl:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend

  npm-db:
    image: jc21/mariadb-aria:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${NPM_MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:?Not defined!}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=npm
      - MYSQL_USER=npm-user
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${NPM_MYSQL_PASSWORD:?Not defined!}
    volumes:
      - npm-db:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - backend
```

`$COLLABORA_DOMAIN` is set to `nextcloud.domain.tld`.

Any ideas what I have done wrong, and how to get my Nextcloud connected to CODE?

Answer (score 0):

What do your custom locations look like?  See, e.g. https://www.collaboraoffice.com/code/nginx-reverse-proxy/

I have a very similar setup, except the collabora instance is not in docker compose, as that never worked for me.

Make sure you have specified your domain environmental variable correctly (dot escaping etc.)